# How to handle a RTSP stream on Python frame by frame?

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp

I have a video that I need to stream over RTSP. This stream will be processed by a python script with OpenCV. **So, I need that this stream must be readable frame by frame in Python**.

I'm on Windows 10, Opencv 3.4, Python 3.6.3. Firewall is disabled.

If I’ll open an any RTSP stream with opencv, there’s no problem: opencv can handle standard rtsp stream from an IP camera.

*BUT*, If I stream a video from VLC over RTSP and try to open it with python-opencv, it raised an error, maybe depending by ffmpeg:

Python code:

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/video")
while True:
    success,image = vidcap.read()
```

Error:

```
[rtsp @ 00000234956b24a0] method SETUP failed: 461 Client error
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:808)
warning: rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/video (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:809)
```

How can I handle this? That's a typical error on opencv, but maybe there is a workaround that I can use. Obviously, the stream video is correct (I opened it with another VLC instance)

I try several things, VLC stream over RTSP seems to not be supported by OpenCV, and i didn’t find any other solutions.

Comment: it could a misconfiguration of your vlc streaming perhaps? i think is better if you add the configuration used to stream with vlc...

Comment: I don't think so, and if it's true, i don't know what can I change. I saw a lot of identical issues on the web about this, and noone talks about VLC configuration problems..

Comment: well, this is just a possibility... In your case OpenCV uses ffmpeg so it could be a difference in the configuration between your streaming and configuration that OpenCV uses/recognizes with ffmpeg... you can also try (if your opencv was compiled with it) gstreamer, take a look to the [flags you can pass](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d), you need OpenCV 3 (not sure exactly which one but 3.2 works)

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, Opencv 3.4, Python 3.6.3. I also tried Gstreamer with no results :(

Comment: The other thing it could be is a firewall... If not, I am out of ideas :(